# Тестирование default метода интерфейса

Tags: java, junit, интерфейс, java-8

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно красиво протестить дефолтный метод чтоб было как меньше дулирования кода, при вот таких условиях:

```
public interface Colorable {

     int getColor();

     default boolean validateColor(int color) {
         return color > 0; //Тут можно поменять getColor() > 0, если это принципиально
     }

}
```

Есть интерфейс и фигуры которые его имплементят(ColorLine, ColorTriangle, ColorPolygon). Я не хотел бы писать в ColorLineTest, ColorTriangleTest, ColorPolygonTest один и тот же юнит тест который проверяет работу этого дефолтного метода. Мне бы хотелось чтоб был какой-нибудь абстрактный класс в котором тестировался этот метод, и все классы типо ColorLineTest, ColorTriangleTest... просто унаследовали этот тест. А писать его нужно будет только если реализующий класс переопределит дефолтную логику.

Answer (score 2):

Пришла мысль про наследование тестовых классов и создание абстрактных тестов, но нет пока времени проверить.

---

Создайте анонимный(mock) объект в классе теста (интерфейса), вам надо только переопределить не дефолтные методы интерфейса:

```
Colorable colorable = new Colorable(){
      public int getColor(){
          //логика работы метода для теста
      }
};
```

и и дальше пишите тесты, которые проверят дефолтный метод. Если вам надо проверить связку дефолтного метода и одной из его реализаций, то лучше это делать в тестах реализации.

Comment: Я правильно понял, что если дефолтный метод опирается на абстрактный то его никак не протестишь в общем случаее?

Comment: @NikaStark все зависит от того, что вы собираетесь тестить. Если вы хотите протестить логику работы дефолтного метода отдельно от всего, то в остальных методах поставьте заглушки, котрые дадут возможность методу отработать как надо. Если вам надо тестировать дефолтный метод в зависимости от реализации интерфейса, то тестируйте в реализации.

Comment: И еще один вопрос - у меня метод _validateColor()_ используется в конструкторах потомков для проверки переданых параметров и получается что при подмене mock(например в ColorLineTest), метод уже вызывается при конструировании и до теста, что совсем не правильно, можете что-то порекомендовать?

Comment: @NikaStark давайте ближе к делу, я конечно могу попробовать представить, то что вы описали, но это не обязательно будет совпадать с вашим представлением. Напишите код, укажите непонятное или проблемное место и я постараюсь помочь.

Comment: Я отправил фрагметы класса и вопрос, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.junit.Test;

public abstract class ColorableTest {

    public Colorable colorFigure = new Colorable() {
       @Override
       public int getColor() {
        return 0;
       }
   };

   @Test
   public void testValidateColor() throws Exception {
       colorFigure.validateColor(911);
   }
}
```

Это то что вы подсказали, если я правильно понял

```
import model.interfaces.Colorable;

public class ColorPoint extends Point implements Colorable {

     private int color;

     public ColorPoint(int x, int y, int color) {
        super(x, y);
        if (!validateColor(color)) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        this.color = color;
     }

     public ColorPoint(Point point, int color) {
        this(point.getX(), point.getY(), color);
     }

     @Override
     public int getColor() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
         if (!validateColor(color)) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
         this.color = color;
    }

    ...

 }
```

Это один из наследников Colorable и вот его тест:

```
import model.interfaces.ColorableTest;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;

public class ColorPointTest extends ColorableTest{


    @BeforeClass
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        this.colorFigure = new ColorLine(new Point(1, 1), new Point(1, 1), 911); //Вот здесь проблема
    }
}
```

Получается чтоб подставить конкретную реализацию нужно проинициализировать переменную colorFigure, и выход что если она нормально создалась то необходимости в тесте нету, а если нет то она упадет до теста.

Comment: зачем вам наследование? в ColorPointTest напишите отдельный тест, который будет создавать объект (1 правильный, 2 неправильный).

Comment: В классе ColorableTest тестируйте только validateColor, т.к. интерфейс знает только о нем. В ColorPointTest  тестируйте ColorLine и его методы. Не стоит делать мешанину. Юнит тесты должны быть простыми и понятными